# How do I use regex capture group as array index?

Tags: regex, tcl

I'm trying to use regsub in TCL to replace a string with the value from an array.

```
array set myArray "
one 1
two 2
"
set myString "\[%one%\],\[%two%\]"

regsub -all "\[%(.+?)%\]" $myString "$myArray(\\1)" newString
```

My goal is to convert a string from "[%one%],[%two%]" to "1,2".  The problem is that the capture group index is not resolved.  I get the following error:

```
can't read "myArray(\1)": no such element in array
while executing
"regsub -all "\[%(.+?)%\]" $myString "$myArray(\\1)" newString"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a 2 step process in Tcl. Your main mistake here is using double quotes everywhere:

```
array set myArray {one 1 two 2}
set myString {[%one%],[%two%]}
regsub -all {\[%(.+?)%\]} $myString {$myArray(\1)} new
puts $new
puts [subst -nobackslash -nocommand $new]
```

```
$myArray(one),$myArray(two)
1,2
```

So we use `regsub` to search for the expression and replace it with the string representation of the variable we want to expand. Then we use the rarely-used [`subst`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/subst.htm) command to perform the variable (only) substitution.

Comment: Works like a champ!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Apart from using `regsub`+`subst` (which is a *decidedly* tricky pair of commands to use safely in general) you can also do relatively simple transformations using `string map`. The trick is in how you prepare the mapping:

```
# It's conventional to use [array set] like this…
array set myArray {
    one 1
    two 2
}
set myString "\[%one%\],\[%two%\]"

# Build the transform
set transform {}
foreach {from to} [array get myArray] {
    lappend transform "\[%$from%\]" $to
}

# Apply the transform
set changedString [string map $transform $myString]
puts "transformed from '$myString' to '$changedString'"
```

As long as each individual thing you want to go from and to is a constant string *at the time of application*, you can use `string map` to do it. The advantage? It's *obviously* correct. It's very hard to make a `regsub`+`subst` transform obviously correct (but necessary if you need a more complex transform; that's the correct way to do %XX encoding and decoding in URLs for example).